# git commit . seves as git add . plus git commit

Tags: git, github

I usually do

```
git add .

git commit
```

But today a friend did just

```
git commit .
```

I wonder if it is the same for all purposes or if I should be aware of something, it has been hard to find in Google anything in this regard.

Comment: You can find more answers by adding “ --help” to the command. There’s lots of complexities in the different commands and options so it’s best to read “help”

Comment: Gold. I somehow imagined that there could be a command like that but I thought it would be gibberish as usual. I tried. What you have commented on today is like gold to me.

Comment: By the way, what I tried was -h as --help just redirected me to the installed help which is similar to the puzzling help online. But the -h alone, man, that is gold.

Comment: I’m glad it helped! You can also get the man page of a git command by using “man git-commit” (replacing commit with the command name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `git commit` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) allows you to specify options and pathspecs:

> ```
> git commit [-a | --interactive | --patch] [-s] [-v] [-u<mode>] [--amend]
>            [--dry-run] [(-c | -C | --fixup | --squash) <commit>]
>            [-F <file> | -m <msg>] [--reset-author] [--allow-empty]
>            [--allow-empty-message] [--no-verify] [-e] [--author=<author>]
>            [--date=<date>] [--cleanup=<mode>] [--[no-]status]
>            [-i | -o] [--pathspec-from-file=<file> [--pathspec-file-nul]]
>            [-S[<keyid>]] [--] [<pathspec>...]
> ```

When using pathspecs such as `.`, the default is to assume the `-o` (aka `--only`) option rather than the `-i` (aka `--include`) option.

> I wonder if it is the same for all purposes or if I should be aware of something ...

When used with `-i`, this is roughly<sup>1</sup> the same as running `git add` on those pathspecs just before running `git commit`.  When used with `-o` or the default, it's different: it creates a temporary index that gets set up from the current commit.  So:

```
git commit .
```

only behaves like:

```
git add . && git commit
```

if you **have not** already done *other* `git add` operations that would add files *not* covered by the `git add .` step!  The whole thing is a bit tricky and I don't recommend using the fancy modes until you're very familiar with Git's index (aka staging area).

The other thing to be aware of, besides the `-i` and `-o` options, is that if the commit *fails* for some reason, the effect of the `git add` step vanishes.  So if you have a pre-commit hook that inspects your commit and rejects it for some reason—e.g., if you left in some debug code, or forgot to put in a bug number in the commit message, or whatever—the `git add` *isn't* done.

---

<sup>1</sup>The adverb *roughly* here covers a lot of ground.

Comment: The keyword I learned today is pathspec. I think that was the reason why I could not found useful information for me. I now understand that, when the pathspec is present, the commit command adds all the changes in that pathspec and commits them. Reading about the -i and -o options, I think the default is actually -o. I'm dizzy right now but I think that if I understood correctly, the -i option on top of committing the changes of the pathspec, also commits staged changes from other paths.

Comment: Oops, you're quite right, `-o` is the default when including pathspecs on the command line. That's the more complicated mode though, so it's *not* like using `git add`!